# Tableview moves down when pop back back to previous view controller

Tags: uitableview, ios7

I m making an app of shopping cart using storyboard.when i move back from list of product ordered controller to list of order controller.order tableview moves down every time when i come back from product list.

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. Please also provide some code you have been working with.

Comment: thanks for your reply my issue is resolved.

Comment: Hi Johny, I have exactly the same issue - could you share how you resolved it? Thanks.

Comment: check your tableview may be you have included some outlet in tableview .take them out of tableview

Comment: Solved it - my problem was to do with AutoLayout.  I had my view pinned to the Top Layout Guide, once I changed this to Superview everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See, carefully if label is placed inside tableviecell contentview, if it is not inside tableviewcell's contentview this problem comes out

Answer (score 3):

Try this might help you.

Add the following to viewDidLoad.

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

This solved my problem of table view moving down after navigating back to view controller.